# An error occurs in PHP Login

Tags: php, mysql

This is a login handler I've written. The username and password both exist in my database. When I try to login, I get errors.

This is my base.php code:

```
?php  
    session_start();  

    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; //Mysql username
    $password=""; //Mysql password
    $db_name="kuih"; // Database name

    //Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("cannot select DB");

    ?>
```

This is my index.php.

```
 <?php include "base.php"; ?> //base.php
             <?php  
            if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))  
            {  
                 ?>  
               <h1>Member Area</h1>  
               <pThanks for logging in! You are <b><?=$_SESSION['username']?></b> and your email address is <b><?=$_SESSION['email']?></b>.</p>  
                   <?php  
            }  
            elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))  
            {  
                $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
                $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));  
                $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'");  
                   if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)  
                {  
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);  
                    $email = $row['email'];  

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;  
                    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;  

                    echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
                    echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";  
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='=2;index.php' />";  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
                    echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";  
                }  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                ?>
```

This is my login form code:

## Member Login

```
               <p>Thanks for visiting! Please either login below, or <a href="register.php">click here to register</a>.</p>  

                <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">  
                <fieldset>  
                    <label for="username">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />  
                    <label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />  
                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />  
                </fieldset>  
                </form>  

               <?php  
            }  
            ?>
```

What do you think about this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Add `print_r($_SESSION)` before `echo "<h1>Error</h1>";` to get more information for debugging.

Comment: **Side notes** Don't use `mysql_*()` - it's deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead. Also, there's no need to escape your password if you're hashing it. The output from MD5 is safe for SQL.

Comment: hi, i use the print_r($_SESSION) but still the same, account cannot be found..

Comment: What does `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($checklogin))` give you?  Is the `username` and `password` combination correct?  Can you verify them in your mysql client?

Comment: Are you saving your users password after hashing md5 or directly in db

Comment: @Vineet1982 yes of course i save it directly

Comment: If you are saving directly then why you are hashing md5 password

Comment: May You print `mysql_num_rows($checklogin)` after query. So that it can be clear if there are no more than one record with same username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) > 0)
```

instead of

```
(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)
```